# Size and location of nepomuk data in KDE4?

Tags: kde-4, nepomuk

I have started using KDE 4.3.2 and I noticed that the size of my home directory had increased in size to about 1.5Gb and was continuing to increase.

I have discovered that it is a result of the data stored by nepomuk in `.kde/share/apps/nepomuk/repository/main/data`.

**Question 1:**

What kind of size should I expect that this data get to?  My home partition is less than 20Gb.

**Question 2:**

If the size is "normal" then can I change the location that is used to store the data via some KDE configuration setting?

My last resort would be to create a symlink to a different location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Q1**: You want to turn off the Strigi document indexer if you want a reasonable db size, or limit the directories it indexes. The tagging/commenting portion of it is pretty lightweight and snappy.

**Q2**: Not that I know of, I'd just symlink it. But removing the Strigi service will reduce it drammatically. Just clear your db data dir after you disable it.